# Problema al agregar filas de una tabla a otra desde un modal javascript mvc

Tags: javascript

Buenas noches tengo dos problemas lo cual solicito ayuda

1. Estoy pasando la informacion que tiene una celda de una Tabla de un modal pero solo me permite pasar hasta 8 columnas la columna 9 no lo pasar la informacion
2. En esta parte de mi codigo despues de :('td:nth-child(8)'); en el nro 8 quiero poner la variable que le asgino a la celda por ejemplo cantidad que es una cadena, es decir no deseo poner el nro sino una variable.
   var cellPrice = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(8)');

ya que en el input del form donde pasa la informacion de la tabla articulos en la ultima columna me debe de calcular el valor venta dependiendo la cantidad que ingrese en el input, lo cual debe tomar la celda anterior para calcular el monto.

```js
//Función para pasar los Artículos a la 
//Tabla Cotización Detalle.
function ArtSel(button) {
    var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cells = row.querySelectorAll('td:not(:last-of-type)');
    agregar(cells);
}

function remove() {
    var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    document.querySelector('#tabCot tbody')
        .removeChild(row);
}

function agregar(cells) {
    var modelo = cells[1].innerText;
    var descri = cells[2].innerText;
    var marca = cells[3].innerText;
    var prevus = cells[4].innerText;
    var prevuc = cells[5].innerText;
    var pesolb = cells[6].innerText;
    var pesokg = cells[7].innerText;
    var price = cells[8].innerText;
    var valven = prevus;

    var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
    /*newRow.setAttribute('data-price', price.substring(1));*/
    newRow.setAttribute('data-price', price);

    newRow.appendChild(createCell(modelo));
    newRow.appendChild(createCell(descri));
    newRow.appendChild(createCell(marca));
    newRow.appendChild(createCell(prevus));
    newRow.appendChild(createCell(prevuc));
    newRow.appendChild(createCell(pesolb));
    newRow.appendChild(createCell(pesokg));
    
    newRow.appendChild(createCell(valven));
    newRow.appendChild(createCell(price));
    /* newRow.appendChild(createCell(f));*/

    var cellInputQty = createCell();
    cellInputQty.appendChild(createInputQty());
    newRow.appendChild(cellInputQty);
    var cellRemoveBtn = createCell();
    cellRemoveBtn.appendChild(createRemoveBtn())
    newRow.appendChild(cellRemoveBtn);

    document.querySelector('#tabCot tbody').appendChild(newRow);
}

function createInputQty() {
    var inputQty = document.createElement('input');
    inputQty.type = 'number';
    inputQty.required = 'true';
    inputQty.className = 'col-xs-1'; 'form-control form-control-sm'
    inputQty.min = 1; // mínimo un producto
    inputQty.onchange = onQtyChange;
    return inputQty;
}

function createRemoveBtn() {
    var btnRemove = document.createElement('button');
    btnRemove.className = 'btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs';
    btnRemove.onclick = remove;
    btnRemove.innerText = 'Eliminar';
    return btnRemove;
}

function createCell(text) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    if (text) {
        td.innerText = text;
    }
    return td;
}

function onQtyChange(e) {
    var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var cellPrice = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(8)');
    var prevPrice = Number(row.getAttribute('data-price'));
    var newQty = Number(this.value);
    var total = prevPrice * newQty;
   /* cellPrice.innerText = '$' + total;*/
    cellPrice.innerText = total;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

si tienes una tabla en html la podemos representar como una matriz y siendo representada como tal podemos recorrerla,

ejemplo: seleccionas el body de la tabla (tbody) esto te dara un arreglo con todos los (tr) luego itera el arreglo y por cada elemento (tr) podemos obtener otro arreglo de los hijos (td) al ser esto un arreglo podemos selecionar directamente cual queremos hijos[4] lugo podemos hacer una variable para guardar los datos de cada elemento hijos[4].text y al final retorna la variable return variable.

toma en cuente que esta variable puede ser un objeto o un arreglo con todos los elementos

En el tfooter de la tabla agrega la misma cantidad de colunna que contiene el tbody, asi podras elegir en que colunna quieres que aparescan los datos

ejemplo:

```html
    <table border="1px" style="border-collapse:collapse; text-align: center;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Colunna-1</th>
                <th>Colunna-2</th>
                <th>Colunna-3</th>
                <th>Colunna-4</th>
                <th>Colunna-5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>0.1</td>
                <td>0.2</td>
                <td>0.3</td>
                <td>0.4</td>
                <td>0.5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1.1</td>
                <td>1.2</td>
                <td>1.3</td>
                <td>1.4</td>
                <td>1.5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2.1</td>
                <td>2.2</td>
                <td>2.3</td>
                <td>2.4</td>
                <td>2.5</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Total:</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: Gracias Ramon logre resolver el caso, pero ahora se me ha presentado otro detalle como agrego 3 filas adicionales que me sume: el total, el igv y el monto total, he visto en otros ejemplos que lo hacen en el footer de la tabla y no se como hacerlo.?

Comment: He realizado algunos cambios en la repuesta donde explico como utilizar el footer de la tabla y como agregar datos en la colunna deseada dentro del footer de la tabla.

Comment: Gracias Ramon por tu pronta respuesta pude resolver gracias a tu recomendación, ahora se me ha presentado otro problema la cual no puedo resolver hasta ahora el caso es que tengo una tabla creada que es la misma imagen es la cotizacion detalle esta tabla esta creada es decir cuando le doy click en el articulo que es el modal pasa el articulo a la tabla el caso es cuando reduzco o pongo a la vista de celular los artículos que paso del modal desaparecen y la cabecera de la tabla se corre, lo que necesito ahora es cuando carga el formulario me debe crear la tabla con los columnas vacías  donde

Comment: después de pasar los artículos del modal agregue a la tabla y tenga el comportamiento de responsive o la vista de celular o Tablet es decir que se ajuste a cualquier dispositivo y esta parte no se como hacerlo, lo hice de esta manera pero no me sale.   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#tabCot').DataTable({
          dom: 'Plfrtip',
          language: {
              searchPanes: {
                  emptyPanes: 'There are no panes to display. :/'

              }
          },
          "retrieve": true,
          "responsive": true
      });
  });

Comment: Por favor me podras dar una mano con este caso.